# WSO2 ESB - Configuration to Develop Services with Developer Studio and Deploy and Debug them on Remote Server

Tags: eclipse, maven, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I want to set up a development environment to develop, build and deploy WSO2 ESB Services. I would like to develop services using WSO2 Developer Studio and debug/deploy them on a remote server.

Here is my configuration:
WSO2 Developer Studio 3.7.1 on Windows 7
WSO2 ESB 3.8.1 on Centos 7

Debugging:
I configured the WSO2 Carbone remote server using Developer Studio Server Tab (OK) and then I tried to create a new remote launch configuration, but developer studio returned with the following exception:

[image: No tab group defined for launch configuration type]

Deploying:
I configured Maven to execute remote deploy, and it runs succesfully, but when I open ESB Console I cannot find any service deployed, I can only find in the wso2carbon.log server log the successful connection with login and password. The following is the maven execution:

```
[INFO] --- maven-car-deploy-plugin:1.0.10:deploy-car (default-deploy-car) @ CappSample ---
[INFO] Deploying to Server...
[INFO] TSPath=c:/bin/wso2/wso2carbon.jks
[INFO] TSPWD=wso2carbon
[INFO] TSType=JKS
[INFO] Server URL=https://wso2-orchestrator.sem:9443
[INFO] UserName=admin
[INFO] Password=admin
[INFO] Operation=deploy
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[INFO] Authentication to https://wso2-orchestrator.sem:9443 successful.
[INFO] Uploading target to https://wso2-orchestrator.sem:9443...
[INFO] Uploading target to https://wso2-orchestrator.sem:9443 completed successfully.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ CappSample ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.856 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-24T17:21:36+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/347M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to remotely debug is to run the server in debug mode and from eclipse create a debug configuration to attach to a Remote Java process.

Deploy from Maven is still not working and waiting for a solution.